# Disable script after time Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, disable

I have a powerup that enables shooting script that is on my player object. powerup script is on my powerup object. Now when I enable script using

```
player.GetComponent<ShootingRocket>().enabled = true;
```

it works fine but when I try to disable script after 5 sec it doesnt do anything. Here is script that I used for that :

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Pickup(other));
    }
}

IEnumerator Pickup(Collider2D player)
{
    player.GetComponent<ShootingRocket>().enabled = true;

    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
    GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);

    player.GetComponent<ShootingRocket>().enabled = false;

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

I have made a variable for time :

```
 public float sec = 5f;
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong. If anyone can help please do.

I can provide any other scripts if you think problem is somewhere else.
I am new at Unity and c#, an coding in general so I would really appreciate it if anyone can help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that `OnTriggerEnter2D` is being called?  Put a `Debug.Log` statement in there.

Comment: As @ben here said check if the OnTriggerEnter is called. Alternatively you could try with Invoke instead of IEnnumerator. The problem is with the colider i thing. Do you have Rigidbody2D attached to your player?

Comment: Thank you for response. I put 'Debug.Log("Picked up!"); ' in 'if (other.CompareTag("Player"))' and it shows that it is picked up in console. Also, shootingRocket script is disabled at start, it gets enabled here 'player.GetComponent<ShootingRocket>().enabled = true;' and that works. When set time passes the gameObject gets destroyed but only the part of the script thats disables script again doesnt work.I also put 'Debug.Log("Disabling "); ' after ' yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);' and that does not show in console.

Answer (score 0):

So

1. Check if this code is actually being called, maybe the collider is not calling anything?
2. Maybe replace 'other.CompareTag("Player")' with 'other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player)
3. Check if the player has this correct tag

Comment: Thank you for response.I put 'Debug.Log("Picked up!"); ' in 'if (other.CompareTag("Player"))' and it shows that it is picked up in console. I also put 'Debug.Log("Disabling "); ' after ' yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);' and that does not show in console. Player has "Player" tag. I tried doing this " Maybe replace 'other.CompareTag("Player")' with 'other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player)" and everything is the same. Also, debug.log in onTriggerEnter function is only called when you pick up the first powerup, it is not showing when you pick it up again.

Comment: Maybee.. instead of 'WaitForSeconds(sec)' do 'WaitForSeconds(5)'.

Comment: And if you know how to use debugger in visual studio - use it. If not, just put Debug.Log every couple of lines and see where does the code stop

Comment: I tried changing WaitForSeconds(sec) to not use a variable and it still did not work. I put Debug,log before and after every action it should take and it doesnt work properly

Comment: This is what my Debug.Log shows in console : https://drive.google.com/file/d/16i-nG227FP3_Ro25kJTqm_MfBsTg_oQy/view?usp=sharing. and this is a screenshot of my code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V0g7L4h2sQpZnReBsF0-VRTqWdUsfFS7/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: And after 5 seconds nothing happen?

Comment: Everything stayed the same. Just like when I used variable : ' public float sec = 5f;'

Comment: It looks like nothing after yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec); is getting activated. I put debug.log every cuople of lines and ti goes from GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false; to StartCoroutine(Pickup(other));. You can see that on scrinshots I provided on links to my Google drive.